# How to push UIViewController to UINavigationController in iOS5 using stroyboards?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I am developing an app for iPhone using iOS5 and xcode 4.2. The scenario is I have two view controllers (say viewControllerA and ciewControllerB) in the storyboard ant the root controller is embedded in the navigation controller, now I want to push viewControLlerB on the  navigation controller on IBAction from a button in viewCotnrollerA. Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a connection between the two views. This can be done by ctrl clicking from the button to the next view in the storyboard.